# casper.waitForSelector not working with dynamic DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is my code,
  The waitForSelector with the same selector works fine before dynamic dom manipultation. not sure if this is a bug.

```
casper.start("http://www.collierscanada.com/en/Properties?t=2")
# works here
casper.waitForSelector('#propertiesListView')
# changing the number of results displayed per page
casper.click('#dk_container_main_0_results_propResultsPerPage > a > span.dk_arrow > span')   casper.waitForSelector('#dk_container_main_0_results_propResultsPerPage.dk_open')  
casper.click('#dk_container_main_0_results_propResultsPerPage > div > ul > li:nth-child(6) > a')
# same selector does not work here
# some dynamic dom manipulation is happening in between
casper.waitForSelector('#propertiesListView')
```

Error

```
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 15000ms expired, exiting
```

Comment: You currently have two `waitForSelector` without anything in between. It can't be that the element vanishes. You probably want to use `casper.thenClick()` instead, because `casper.click()` is executed immediately and should throw an error. Please make your issue more clear.

Comment: @ArtjomB. click executes immediately and it changes the components in the page. I verified this by screenshot. And what happens is some components are replaced in the dom is what i beleive. After this the same waitForSelector fails. If i dump HTML i can see the component there

Comment: @ArtjomB. using then makes it work. I don't seem to get the difference. After clicking a dropdown I want to wait until results appear, why then works. I am a bit confused when to use then and when not to

Comment: You mean `thenClick` instead of `click`? `click` is not asynchronous like all `then*` and `wait*` functions.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No I used then -> wait it worked. After clicking, I immediately start waiting for a selector to appear(in case when i am not using then). After the click action is done, I use a call back to function to look if a selector appears (when using then). What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
casper.start("http://www.collierscanada.com/en/Properties?t=2")
casper.waitForSelector('#propertiesListView', function() {
    casper.click('#dk_container_main_0_results_propResultsPerPage > a > span.dk_arrow > span')
});
casper.waitForSelector('#dk_container_main_0_results_propResultsPerPage.dk_open').thenClick('#dk_container_main_0_results_propResultsPerPage > div > ul > li:nth-child(6) > a')
casper.waitForSelector('#propertiesListView')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting here. While your code may answer the question, it is better to include some explanation. That way, the OP and any other visitor will be able to get a deeper understanding of your solution.